# ¿Cómo especificar el tamaño de los parámetros de una base de datos PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Intenté inicializar una base de datos con un archivo `schema.sql` para PostreSQL en Heroku pero tengo un problema con el tamaño que quiero data a los parámetros de la table. En efecto con la linea `id int(11) auto_increment PRIMARY KEY` obtengo el error :

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 2:   id int(11) auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
```

Aqui esta el archivo `schema.sql`

```
drop table if exists users;
create table users (
  id int(11) auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(100),
  email varchar(100),
  username varchar(30),
  password varchar(100),
  register_date timestamp not null
);
```

Y aqui esta el error :

```
mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa/myflaskapp$ heroku pg:psql < schema.sql--> Connecting to postgresql-clean-86569
NOTICE:  table "users" does not exist, skipping
DROP TABLE
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 2:   id int(11) auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
                ^
NOTICE:  table "articles" does not exist, skipping
DROP TABLE
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 2:   id int(11) PRIMARY KEY,
                ^
```

Comment: Los datos de tipo `int` ya tienen un tamaño fijo, no puedes especificar `int(11)`. ¿Que es lo que buscas?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Error de traducción de MySQL a PostgreSQL :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgresQL no acepta tamaños `int` pero `NUMERIC`. Puede hacer `column_Name NUMERIC (11)` O con una restricción, forzando a estar entre rangos.